# How do I improve the time it takes to load and parse files

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

So I 'm trying to load some data that my website can use in order to display some items.
Each item is in a json format and this is what I'm doing.

When the user sends a request to load the page, it then tries to load 400 items (there are in total 26000, i'm just using 400 to test)
and obviously 400 is going to take a lot of time, and it does that when the user clicks next as well since it's using pagination.

And my idea was that maybe I could load like 50 at a time, which would make it way more efficient!
But I'm not sure what I could do in order to implement that thought.
I tried using foreach skip and take but I couldnt really come up with a decent algorithm.
Each file is between 1 and 2KB.

Would it improve the speed a lot if I just made it one file? Seeing how it would try to load it each time I click next or another page number.

```
public ActionResult Items(int? page)
        {
            var items = new List<ItemModel>();
            var path = @"C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\items-json";
            var itemFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path);

            for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    var json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(itemFiles[i]);

                    var itemObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ItemModel>(json);
                    items.Add(itemObject);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                }
            }

            var pageNumber = page ?? 1;
            var onePageOfItems = items.ToPagedList(pageNumber, 10);
            //ViewBag.OnePageProducts = onePageOfProducts;
            return View(onePageOfItems);
        }
```

Comment: What does the data look like inside each JSON file? Can you store it in a SQLite database file instead of individual files on-disk?

Comment: Here is an example
https://hatebin.com/vumfdwvcbz

Answer (score 0):

(My answer is assuming that you have to read individual files from-disk instead of storing data in a different medium such as a SQLite database file).

First-off, there's a huge bug in your code: the `Directory.GetFiles()` method **does not guarantee any specific ordering of files** - and pagination is meaningless without a defined ordering.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_
>
> The order of the returned file names is not guaranteed; use the Sort method if a specific sort order is required.

Assuming that you want to order by filename, then we can use that as the basis of paging, and then read only those files.

[The code below uses *real* async file IO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/using-async-for-file-access) (by creating a `FileStream` with `async: true`) which means it uses [Windows' built-in Overlapped IO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/synchronization-and-overlapped-input-and-output) to handle asynchronous file-reads from multiple files - which should be much faster than serially synchronously reading from other files.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

public async Task<ActionResult> Items( Int32? page )
{
    const String path = @"C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\items-json\";
    const Int32 pageSize = 50;
    Int32 pageIndex = ( ( page ?? 1 ) - 1 ); // 0-based indexing!

    IReadOnlyList<FileInfo> files = new DirectoryInfo( path ).GetFiles("*.json");

    List<FileInfo> filesToRead = files
        .OrderBy( fi => fi.Name, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase )
        .Skip( pageSize * pageIndex )
        .Take( pageSize )
        .ToList();

    IReadOnlyList<ItemModel> items = await ReadJsonFilesAsync<ItemModel>( filesToRead ).ConfigureAwait(false);

    return this.View( items );
}

private static async Task<IReadOnlyList<T>> ReadJsonFilesAsync<T>( IEnumerable<FileInfo> jsonFiles )
{
    // Asynchronously read from all the files at once and let Windows' Overlapped-IO take care of it:
    List<Task<T>> tasks = jsonFiles
        .Select( fi => ReadJsonFileAsync<T>( fi.FullName ) )
        .ToList();

    T[] items = await Task.WhenAll( tasks ).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return items;
}


private static async Task<T> ReadJsonFileAsync<T>( String path )
{
    const Int32 asyncFileStreamBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; // Adjust this to be a reasonably sized multiple of 4096 that's at least larger than any file you'll process.

    using( FileStream fs = new FileStream( path: path, mode: FileMode.Open, access: FileAccess.Read, share: FileShare.Read, bufferSize: asyncFileStreamBufferSize, useAsync: true )
    using( StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader( fs ) )
    {
        // Annoyingly, JsonTextReader and JsonSerializer doesn't support true async deserialization - but the entire file will be buffered into a string anyway so it's moot - so we great perf at the cost of somewhat higher memory usage.
        String fileText = await rdr.ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>( fileText );
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a very interesting approach! Now if I was storing it in a different medium, such as a SQL database, would I just create a database called something like Items and model the database after each property of a file? I feel as if that's an interesting approach, but I don't see how that's faster. Thank you for your answer, I appreciate it!

Comment: @RileyVarga Reading from a single database file (or a single large file in general) is much faster than reading from lots of small files due to how HDDs (and even SSDs) work. It's too much detail for me to go into in this comment, but this is why database systems like MySQL, MSSQL Server, and others all store everything in huge, but single, database files.

Comment: @RileyVarga What you're describing about mapping/modelling a database row to match a class' properties is exactly what an ORM like NHibernate or Entity Framework does. I recommend you read up on those.

Comment: Very interesting! So if I were to store it in a database, would I just mash them all into 1 json file which is an array of items?

Comment: Yeah I use EF CF so that's what I figured I would do rather than having a big string of json on the database, but I'm not sure what would be better

Comment: @RileyVarga I wouldn't do that because you can't trivially append to a serialized JSON array due to JSON's strict rules about `,` and `]` characters (you would also have to build and maintain an index to avoid having to read the entire file to locate each record in the fie (cont'd...)

Comment: ...this is why it's popular to store naked JSON objects on each line of a file without being wrapped in an array and only parsing each line as JSON - however this approach only works well for logging or bulk data for one-time "extract-transform-load" operations - for all other purposes (such as storing ordered data) it's still impractical because you can't perform random-reads - that's why you need to build and maintain an index.

Comment: Oh right, I forgot about it being very strict, so in other words, structure a database from the model, and store all the items in the database as entires? To me that feels like it would do the same as what I was doing with reading each file individually, but you did mention that it was on a hardware level that could make it slow like a harddrive, so maybe it wouldnt be as bad

Comment: @RileyVarga No, as I said, there is a **massive** performance hit from reading from lots of small files compared to reading from a single large file - and when reading records from a large file you will need to index it so you don't need to read the entire file (to index a file you build a map of each record's identifier to its byte offset in the file) which is a lot of work - but if you use a DBMS like SQLite then that work is already all done for you. Don't forget having to synchronize too (i.e. ensure one thread can safely read from a file while another thread writes to the same file).

Comment: Oh! Okay yeah that makes sense! I'll probably move over to that approach in the future, that doesn't sounds too shabby

Answer (score 0):

Parallel programming can help reduce the time a lot, below is a simplified sample:

```cs
Parallel.ForEach(itemFiles, file =>
{
    var json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file);
    var itemObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ItemModel>(json);
    items.Add(itemObject);
}
```

Additionally, this article compares the performance of file reading methods:

[C# .Net: Fastest Way to Read Text Files](https://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/fastest-way-to-read-text-files)